# Query not updating a field in Mysql With cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a table provider_photos with the given structure

```
id Primary  int(11) 
provider_id int(11)
photo_name  varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci       
photo_org_name  varchar(50) latin1_swedish_ci
photo_order int(2)
photo_selected  varchar(256)
```

I am using CakePHP framework, following is the code to update the table

```
App::Import('Model','ProviderPhoto');
  $ProviderPhoto =  new ProviderPhoto();
  $this->data["ProviderPhoto"]["id"] = $_POST['id'];
  $this->data["ProviderPhoto"]["photo_selected"] = 'N';
  $this->data["ProviderPhoto"]["photo_name"] = "picname7";
  $this->data["ProviderPhoto"]["photo_org_name"] = "sliderOrgName7";

  $ProviderPhoto->save($this->data['ProviderPhoto']);
```

The issue I am facing is that, I am not able to update the field photo_selected. The other fields change correctly.
No errors are shown.
I have created that field afterwards

Comment: Are you sure that updated all fields except `photo_selected` ?

Comment: Delete the cache (`app/tmp/cache/models`) and try again. And judging from the name and the value you'd better use a `TINYINT(1)` column instead. Also you never instantiate models directly (except for in unit tests maybe), you use `ClassRegistry::init()`, `Controller::$uses` or `Controller::loadModel()`!

Comment: @ndm Could you also consider replying to [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275752/query-not-updating-a-field-in-mysql-with-cakephp/28279780#comment135492537_28279780) in the accepted answer. Since you answered here first too before the answerer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you deleted the  model cache in tmp/cache/models?
When you change anything in the model relastion or database structure you should empty this cache.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This worked for me. I just want to know if deleting `tmp/cache/models` directly on my production server has any 'risks'. I'm a bit paranoid and just made a backup of the folder rather than deleting it. My server ran smoothly and recreated it. Just want to confirm any caveats that we need to be aware of in such situations.

Comment: @joeljpa Out of the box, everything that CakePHP creates in `tmp` is safe to delete. Whether your application or other third party code may store additional stuff in there that isn't safe to delete, I can't speak to that, other than this would be wrong and would need to be fixed, as temp data really should always be safe to delete.

Answer (score -1):

```
App::Import('Model','ProviderPhoto');
$ProviderPhoto =  new ProviderPhoto();
$ProviderPhoto->id = $this->request->data['id'];
$ProviderPhoto->saveField('photo_name', 'picname7');
```

Comment: Its not updating the field photo_selected, other fields are updated correctly. I have added this field after the table and modal  was created.

Comment: Did you mean, /cake/libs/model/schema.php

Comment: app/Config/schema/schema.php

Comment: Sorry I can't see schema in the following path

Comment: You never instantiate models directly (except for in unit tests maybe), you use `ClassRegistry::init()`, `Controller::$uses` or `Controller::loadModel()`! Also please note that answers should not be code only, but explain how they fix the problem.  So instead of advertising your website, you should spend a few minutes thinking about how your code is relevant to the problem.

Comment: I've removed your link to your personal website homepage. If you want you can put it on your profile page.